ROS2 cannot import message from another package
reading ROS2 Humble tutorial. I have a package visual_docking_vision written in Python. It is to identify Aruco markers. I want to publish position of detected marker so I want a custom message for that.
There is written in tutorial I cannot add custom messages in Python packages. So I add this in another package, where I also want to add C++ nodes. So my workspace has 2 packages:

visual_docking (C++, I store msg/ArucoMarker.msg here)
visual_docking_vision (Python, I use there opencv to detect)

The problem is, I cannot import ArucoMarker msg from visual_docking in visual_docking_vision. I always get following error that node cannot find package:
from visual_docking.msgs import ArucoMarker
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'visual_docking'

In general, message is built correctly as I can run:
$ ros2 interface show visual_docking/msg/ArucoMarker 
geometry_msgs/Point center
        float64 x
        float64 y
        float64 z
int64 theta


I updated project files inside visual_docking_vision as following:
vision.py (Node source file)
from visual_docking.msgs import ArucoMarker

package.xml
<package format="3"> 
<!-- ... -->
  <exec_depend>message_runtime</exec_depend>                                                                                                                                                                   
  <exec_depend>visual_docking</exec_depend> <!-- ArucoMarker msg -->   

After modifications, I run  commands to rebuild node and run:
colcon build --packages-select visual_docking_vision
source install/setup.bash
ros2 run visual_docking_vision vision_node

Both packages stay in same workspace. Please help, according to docs I should just put a package name that stores message in package.xml and that's it.
Additionally, due to issues with python packaging in ROS2 I use custom venv as described here:
https://github.com/ros2/ros2/issues/1094#issuecomment-2067759726
BTW I noticed that ROS2 doesn't respect what is put in package.xml... I can put a random <exec_depend>visual_dockingxxxx</exec_depend> and colcon doesn't complain at all...

First:

There is written in tutorial I cannot add custom messages in Python packages.

Where does it say so? I think what you mean is that it has to be a CMake package?
In any case: best practice is to define a separate package for message definitions.
This package can then be sourced and used by other packages (both c++ or python).
This is covered by the tutorial, both for C++ and Python packages. So you should follow the tutorial step by step, and if it does not work, specify at which step exactly you experience issues.
Second:
It is also best practice to use standard messages, if possible.
Given that the Aruco marker position semantically is a pose, I would suggest to use the pose message instead of defining your own message.
